# Is it possible to refer local JS library in UIWebView which is loading remote web page?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

```
<head>
<script src="file:///.../jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

and UIWebView loaded remote URL as `[self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];` URL in request is having page .this page contains part of it as shown above refering local jquery file. can it work ? if I put jquery file localy in iOS application bundle.

Any help is appreciated .Thanks